# In Angular2 NGmodule .I want to load 2 different sets of route modules based on Condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In Angular2 .I want to load 2 different sets of route modules  1 for jobseekers and other for employers . The the urls are the same but the modules for jobseekers and employers will be different . There fore I want to dynamically load the route modules bases on the session of the login .Is there a way i can do that ??   or is there an  better way it can implemented in angular2

basically i want to be able to load ngModules based on condition

Below is the sample code .

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule,customRoutes.getCustomRoutes(),
            SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'  },
    CanActivateGuard,AccountService, ProfileService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

  constructor(private _http:Http,@Inject(AccountService) authService:AccountService) {


  }
```

// Custom Route

```
export class customRoutes {

  public customRoutes;
  constructor(@Inject(AccountService)  accountService:AccountService) {


  }

 getCustomRoutes() {
    return this.customRoutes = (accountService.getCheckEmployer())?JobSeekerRoutes:EmployerRoutes;
  }

}
```

// But getCustomRoutes need to be a static method to be called in the NGModule . But if i make it static I would get access to the accountService object.

(Is there a better way to achieve the feature of loading different routes based on user session)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately configuring routes at runtime is not supported at this time. Routes are specified when the Angular application is bootstrapped an one cannot change them afterwards.

Comment: If I want to load modules based on certain condition is that possible ? Say if employer session is set  I need to Load in the modules specific to employer only